# Why my process just opens a blank window and closes it immediately?

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I am trying to call convert.exe trough Process class from C# to convert a specific image to another format like this:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(inputFilePath, Convert.FromBase64String(image.Content));
Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(HttpContext.Current).Log(new Error(new Exception("Succesfully wrote the image to: " + inputFilePath)));

var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", inputFilePath, outputFilePath);

proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q16\convert.exe";
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

I do not understand why it opens a command prompt and shuts it down immediately...Do you see any error in the code? The path to convert.exe is fine for sure...

Comment: Probably it ran into an error and immediately terminated. (you're calling a console app, right?)  Any chance you can see the output before it disappears?

Comment: Are you saying you don't want the command prompt to show at all, or are you saying it shouldnt be closing that quickly?

Comment: Do your input and/or output paths possibly have spaces in them and are you sure they're valid? ... You should output the file to run and the paths to console to test if you can execute them from the commandline manually.

Comment: I would like to see the error because the conversion is not working...(I know that it's not working because I don't see the result file).

Comment: Check the variable `proc.ExitCode` after `proc.WaitForExit()` returns.

Comment: You're using Elmah, is this a web application that is trying to execute a process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a Stream to the Process object to capture the output.

see the [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput)

Comment: I've now discovered that the conversion works nice but I was indeed wanted to capture the output so I will mark you're answer as satisfying my need.

Answer (score 4):

You web application is running in the context of the IIS user, it may not have access to execute convert.exe.  You could either try running IIS under a specific user (like you, if convert.exe works for you) or grant access in some way to let convert.exe run).

Comment: Okay, if you're going to downvote, at least let me know why.  It's a perfectly viable possibility.